# Fail2ban compatibility debian debian jessie systemd

Tags: debian, fail2ban

Fail2ban debian jessie package not working:

On fresh debian jessie with `openssh-server` (*tested in docker container*):

```
root@2b29327677c8:/# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.3
root@2b29327677c8:/# apt-get install fail2ban
root@2b29327677c8:/# apt-cache policy fail2ban
fail2ban:
  Installed: 0.8.13-1
  Candidate: 0.8.13-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.8.13-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

root@2b29327677c8:/# service fail2ban start
Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2banERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/auth.log
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for ssh jail
 failed!
```

*Debian jessie do not have /var/log/auth.log*

How to use fail2ban on debian jessie to watch ssh connections ?

Comment: @ansi_lumen You're diggin up a big debate ^^

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/

Comment: @MichaelHampton https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770171

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [fail2ban version 0.9.0](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/releases/tag/0.9.0) introduced a systemd journal backend:

> systemd journal backend has been created. This has a dependency on
>   python-systemd. To use journal match in filters there is a
>   "journalmatch".

However, Debian 8 (jessie) has [fail2ban version 0.8.13](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/fail2ban) and the [changelog as of package version 0.8.13-1](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/fail2ban/fail2ban_0.8.13-1_changelog) has no indication that this functionality would have been been backported either.

This seems like a bit of an oversight considering the use of systemd, but would explain your problems. (You can obviously still monitor anything that is written to plain log files.)

Comment: You're correct! I can install >=0.9.0 fail2ban package with
http://neuro.debian.net/ repo. But my question include how to configure
fail2ban in this case. (i tried to configure it with backend=systemd and
some other config without success)